# Archlinux & Windows8: Clock issues on Windows

Tags: windows, time, timezone, archlinux

Hi there,

I had to install Windows on my machine recently for a multiplatform development project.
I installed windows first, and reinstalled arch linux on top, to get a clean install and grub.

Sadly, I am facing timezone issues since then, on Windows. My clock behaves normally on Arch but on windows, I get a 1 to 5 hour delay between the real time (UTC+1 Paris) and the time I actually have. I tried to adjust by changing the timezone, but everytime I restart my laptop, the timezone changes again.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Hope you can help, =)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find your hardware clock is set to UTC in linux (the default) which then messes up your windows time on each boot as it is expecting the hardware clock to be set to the local time. This can be checked with:

```
$ timedatectl status | grep local
> RTC in local TZ: no
```

And use:

```
$ timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

to set it to localtime. This should (hopefully) fix your problem.

Alternatively you can configure windows to use a UTC hardware clock, the details of which can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time#UTC_in_Windows).